# Does JVM manage class code by function? Is splitting a large decision function effective on memory usage?

Tags: java, optimization, memory-management, coding-style, jvm

## Problem

In a server-based java solution we need a bigger lookup table with static values (about 300 kB but the data increases yearly with new values for the next year).

Usually the table would be placed in the database, but we now discussed to implement it in a Java-class as Java code. I would program the class just with one member function which calculates the table value. No object instances or other memory needs - just code.

## The Coded Table

```
public class Lookup {

 public static float getValue (int year, int c1, int c2, int c3) {
    if (year == 2012) {
       if (c1 == 1) { // about 70 kByte of code
             ....
            return 7.34;
       }
    }
    if (year == 2013) { // about 70 kByte of code
       if (c1 == 1) {
         ....
            return 8.23;
    }
  }

}
```

## My question

The table increases yearly and the older years are very rarely used. Would it be an advantage to implement a function per year instead of one having the year as a Parameter? Would it be an advantage ot implement a class per year? 
Would the JVM detect that the older years are not used and free memory?

## Special Functions Per Year

Is this better? More flexible concering memory consumption?

```
public class Lookup {

  public static float getValue (int year, int c1, int c2, int c3) {
    if (year == 2012) return Lookup.getValue2012 (c1, c2, c3);
    if (year == 2013) return Lookup.getValue2012 (c1, c2, c3);
  }

  public static float getValue2012 (int year, int c1, int c2, int c3) {
    if (c1==1) { // about 70 kByte of code
             ....
            return 7.34;
    }
  }
  public static float getValue2013 (int year, int c1, int c2, int c3) {
    if (c1==1) { // about 70 kByte of code
             ....
            return 8.23;
    }
 }
}
```

## Special Classes Per Year

Or is this better? More flexible concering memory usage?

```
public class Lookup {

  public static float getValue (int year, int c1, int c2, int c3) {
    if (year == 2012) return Lookup2012.getValue (c1, c2, c3);
    if (year == 2013) return Lookup2013.getValue (c1, c2, c3);
  }

}
public class Lookup2012 {

  public static float getValue (int year, int c1, int c2, int c3) {
    if (c1==1) { // about 70 kByte of code
             ....
            return 7.34;
    }
  }
}

public class Lookup2013 {

  public static float getValue (int year, int c1, int c2, int c3) {
    if (c1==1) { // about 70 kByte of code
             ....
            return 8.23;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a really, really bad idea. Why don't you implement this table as... a table?

Comment: Hi larsmans, we are still in the decision process. Implementing a table means implementing management interfaces for System Operation for these additional tables (Import, Export, rights management, etc.). These modules cost implementation power and risks in implemenation, qualification, testing, etc. Hardcoding avoids that. Also, with this slow frequency of updates data structure changes are very likely and code can handle that much better than a management interface. We will check alternatives very carefully.

Comment: A table does not necessarily mean a table in a database. You can store it in a flat file, then read that into memory as a simple array and index into it. The proposed solution is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: This data should be loaded dynamically, not hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I don't think it would make any difference splitting static methods across classes or having them in the same class. The reason being, irrespective of where they are declared static methods get loaded into the JVM only once during start up by the class loader and remain in memory till the webapp is undeployed. Also, the memory for the method is reclaimed once the method finishes executing and all the local references are garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks for the clear statement. I have the same understanding. I wanted to ensure that this is really true.